# R readBin not reading binary data correctly

Tags: r

I am trying to use R to read a binary file with six simple data items (of type double), which I know where written correctly to the file by another C code:

```
x=-2.798281e-01 y=-2.044148e+00 z=9.155162e-02 vx=0.000000e+00   vy=0.000000e+00 vz=0.000000e+00
```

However, when I use these lines in R

```
bincon     = file('mybinaryfile', 'rb')
parcoords  = readBin(bincon, double(),6)
```

all I get is this (only three wrong numbers!):

```
> parcoords
[1]  -2.353189e+00  5.117028e-315   0.000000e+00
```

What could the issue be?

Comment: Without access to the file, it would be pretty hard to know.

Comment: Or at least share the results of `dput(readBin(bincon", raw(), 100) )` so we can see what bytes are actually in your file.

Comment: All I get is raw(0). I would like to add that if I write an integer to the file, I can read it correctly with "readBin(bincon, integer(),1)"

Comment: If you get `raw(0)` that would imply the file is empty, or you've already read the bytes with another command. Make sure you do it immediately after you open the file.

Comment: I get "as.raw(c(0xa2, 0x45, 0x8f, 0xbe, 0x54, 0xd3, 0x02, 0xc0, 0x6a, 
0x7f, 0xbb, 0x3d, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00))".

Answer (score 2):

Well, your file appears to be 24 byes long so if you have 6 values, each must be only 4 bytes long whereas R expectes double values to be 8 bytes long. You can specify a size parameter to `readBin()`

```
readBin(bincon, double(), 6, size=4)
# [1] -0.27982813 -2.04414845  0.09155162  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
```